# ¿Cómo abreviar este código de estilo en javascript?

Tags: css, javascript-objeto

Yo tengo un `<div id="bar">` y quiero programarle un estilo con javascript, así:

```
var banner = document.getElementById('bar');
banner.style.background = 'transparent';
banner.style.display = 'inherit';
banner.style.position = 'relative';
banner.style.height = '100';
```

No lo hago con css porque es para un evento, pero mi pregunta es ¿cómo hago para no escribir varias veces `banner.style.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparte de las sugerencias que te dan, también tienes la opción de escribirlo en una linea escribiendo el valor como propiedades CSS, por ejemplo así.

```
var banner = document.getElementById('bar').style = 'background-color:blue;height:100px;width:100px';
```

Dependiendo de para que lo uses te puede resultar mas conveniente de una u otra forma.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let stylingBar = bar.style;

stylingBar["color"] = "red"
```

```html
<div id="bar">Bar</div>
```

Puedes guardar el `.style` en una variable y después especificar el estilo que deseas cambiar

O puedes usar una función

```js
const cambiarEstilo = (regla, valor, elemento) => {
  if (typeof regla == "string" && typeof valor == "string") {
    if (document.body.contains(elemento)) {
      return elemento.style[regla] = valor;
    } else {
      return bar.style[regla] = valor;
    }
  }
}

cambiarEstilo("color","red")
```

```html
<div id="bar">Bar</div>
```

Usaremos `typeof` para comprobar que hemos recibido un string tanto de regla como de valor

Puedes especificar el elemento al que quieres cambiarle el CSS, si no se especifica se cambiará directamente a `bar`

Usa el `body.contains` para comprobar que el elemento, si es que se da, existe en el DOM

Answer (score 1):

La verdad que en este caso mi amigo lo más recomendable pienso sería crear una clase en css con las propiedades que tu quieres, de manera de cada vez que se lo agregue hagas asi:

```
miElementoHtml.classList.add('miClaseCss');
```

o en vez de `add` podría ser con `toggle` o `remove`, todo dependiendo de tu caso.

En el caso de que se reuse al css, lo unico que vería como "mas viable" sería guardar en una variable los styles, de esta manera:

```
let myHtmlStyles = document.querySelector('.miSelector').style;
```

de esa manera cuando asignes un estilo solo pondrás:

```
 myHtmlStyles.color = 'red';
```

En vez de:

```
myHtmlStyles.style.color = 'red';
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método [`add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#m%C3%A9todos) del Objeto [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) presente en cada elemento del DOM.

De esta forma puedes escribir una función que reciba una lista de clases y aplique cada una de las mismas al elemento con una sola llamada. Puedes hacerlo mediante un bucle `for` o usando la [sintaxis de expansión (*spread*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread), por ejemplo:

```js
var divBar = document.getElementById("bar");

var classList = ["foo", "baz", "qux", "quux", "quuz"];

function applyStylesBucle(element, styles) {
  styles.forEach(style => {
    divBar.classList.add(style);
  });
}

function applyStyles(element, styles) {
  divBar.classList.add(...styles);
}

document.getElementById("bucle").addEventListener("click", e => {
  applyStylesBucle(divBar, classList);
});

document.getElementById("cadena").addEventListener("click", e => {
  applyStyles(divBar, classList);
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background: red;
}

.baz {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.qux {
  height: 30px;
}

.quux {
  color: white;
}

.quuz {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">Lorem ipsum</div>
<br>
<button id="bucle">Usar Bucle</button>
<button id="cadena">Usar Spread</button>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.